# Legal to walk around with a wooden rod in Alabama?

Tags: united-states, weapons, alabama

I am a very poor skateboarder, and would like to use a shovel handle as a "dry-land gondola paddle" to make navigation easier. Could such a thing be considered a weapon if I were to go about in public in a city with this?

Comment: Given that you can openly carry a firearm in Alabama without a permit, it would be a bit ridiculous if you couldn't carry a wooden staff.  But stranger laws exist.

Comment: Could you clarify for us the uninformed, non-radaical skateboard dudes, what exactly a dry-land gondola is?  Are there purpose built paddles?  Are they allowed for use in your city?  Am I correct in my understanding that the shovel blade (the part that goes into the ground) will be removed from the shaft?   What material will the shaft and handle be made of?

Comment: @hszmv I just mean a wooden shovel handle, sans blade, like in [this link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/True-Temper-48-in-Open-Back-Shovel-Handle-2037300/100605629). By "dry-land gondola paddle," I mean I intend to propel and steer myself using the pole instead of the normal means, as if the skateboard were a gondola.